# Using WHERE MATCH with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I'm getting this error message:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE c.id =
>   159 AND ( supervisor_agent.superviso'

Please what am I missing? Every thing works when I remove:

```
AND WHERE c.id = 159 AND  
(
supervisor_agent.supervisor_id = 5
OR
ind.agent_id = 5
)
```

From the query below;

```
SELECT

'individual' AS type, ind.id, ind.uid, CONCAT_WS(' ', ind.last_name, ind.first_name, ind.middle_name) AS title, NULL AS phone, c.name AS country, s.name AS state, l.name AS lga, MATCH (ind.uid,ind.tin,ind.email,ind.first_name,ind.last_name,ind.middle_name,ind.maiden_name,ind.gender,ind.marital_status) AGAINST ('+mbah*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 

FROM individuals AS ind

LEFT JOIN supervisor_agent ON ind.agent_id = supervisor_agent.agent_id LEFT JOIN countries AS c ON ind.country_origin_id = c.id LEFT JOIN states AS s ON ind.state_origin_id = s.id LEFT JOIN lgas AS l ON ind.lga_origin_id = l.id 

WHERE MATCH (uid,tin,email,first_name,last_name,middle_name,maiden_name,gender,marital_status) AGAINST ('+mbah*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND WHERE c.id = 159 AND  
(
supervisor_agent.supervisor_id = 5
OR
ind.agent_id = 5
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
AND WHERE ...
```

Just put `AND`

```
SELECT

'individual' AS type, ind.id, ind.uid, CONCAT_WS(' ', ind.last_name, ind.first_name, ind.middle_name) AS title, NULL AS phone, c.name AS country, s.name AS state, l.name AS lga, MATCH (ind.uid,ind.tin,ind.email,ind.first_name,ind.last_name,ind.middle_name,ind.maiden_name,ind.gender,ind.marital_status) AGAINST ('+mbah*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score 

FROM individuals AS ind

LEFT JOIN supervisor_agent ON ind.agent_id = supervisor_agent.agent_id LEFT JOIN countries AS c ON ind.country_origin_id = c.id LEFT JOIN states AS s ON ind.state_origin_id = s.id LEFT JOIN lgas AS l ON ind.lga_origin_id = l.id 

WHERE MATCH (uid,tin,email,first_name,last_name,middle_name,maiden_name,gender,marital_status) AGAINST ('+mbah*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND c.id = 159 AND  
(
supervisor_agent.supervisor_id = 5
OR
ind.agent_id = 5
)
```

Comment: Facepalm ... thanks for your swift and helpful response.